# Select distinct not working in complex pl/pgsql query

Tags: postgresql, group-by, sql-order-by, distinct, plpgsql

I have this query in a pl/pgsql function. I am using PostgreSQL 10.

```
FOR firstrecord IN 
EXECUTE format( 

 'SELECT  vans.id as vid, adidas.id as aid, 
 vans.color, adidas.color, vans.type, adidas.type 
 FROM shoes 
 FULL JOIN adidas ON shoes.id = adidas.id 
 FULL JOIN shoes ON shoes.id=vans.id
 WHERE  adidas.code = 607 and vans.code = 304 '  )              

 USING acode , vcode 

END LOOP;
```

This works, but I would like to enforce a `SELECT DISTINCT` on `vans.id` AND 
 `adidas.id`. 
This is the closest I got

```
FOR firstrecord IN 
EXECUTE format( 

 'SELECT DISTINCT ON  (adidas.id)  vans.id as vid, adidas.id as aid, 
 vans.color, adidas.color, vans.type, adidas.type 
 FROM shoes 
 FULL JOIN adidas ON shoes.id = adidas.id 
 FULL JOIN shoes ON shoes.id=vans.id
 WHERE  adidas.code = 607 and vans.code = 304 
 ORDER BY adidas.id,vans.id'  )              

 USING acode , vcode 

END LOOP;
```

If I try to do something like `SELECT DISTINCT ON  (adidas.id, vans.id)` the `DISTINCT` does not work, I get duplicates in result.

If I do `SELECT DISTINCT vans.id as vid, adidas.id as aid` , still the `DISTINCT` does not work, I get duplicates in result.

How do I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: There might be a better solution, but clarify something first please: You have `shoes` twice in your `FROM` list. The 2nd one is a typo and should be `vans` instead? While editing your question, please also explain what the query is supposed to achieve, and why you use dynamic SQL with `EXECUTE`, which seems unnecessary. You are not even referencing the parameters provided in the `USING` clause and wouldn't need dynamic SQL even if you did ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're seeing now, if you use DISTINCT ON( expression1, expression2) it'll count all the combinations of the two expression as distinct, including when one is NULL as distinct from any non-NULL value. It seems like you want just one expression that takes in to account the ids from both tables. You can get this using the coalesce function, like so:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON  ( coalesce(adidas.id, vans.id))  vans.id as vid, adidas.id as aid, 
vans.color, adidas.color, vans.type, adidas.type 
FROM shoes 
FULL JOIN adidas ON shoes.id = adidas.id 
FULL JOIN vans ON shoes.id = vans.id
WHERE  adidas.code = 607 and vans.code = 304 
ORDER BY coalesce(adidas.id, vans.id)
```

This works in this case because if both are non-NULL, they should match one another, and if one is NULL the coalesce statement will return the non-NULL value.

Comment: Great idea to use the `coalesce`. Thanks